# Trigger Airflow DAG from Python source code, cannot find Sqlite table "dag"

Tags: python, sqlite, jupyter-notebook, environment-variables, airflow

I want to invoke an Airflow DAG definition from within a Python script (a Jupyter notebook actually).

I made sure the environment variables that I use for the `airflow` command are set (e.g. `AIRFLOW_HOME`) with `python-dotenv` to load a `.env` file inside the Jupyter notebook. This `.env` file contains various environment variables included `AIRFLOW_HOME`:

```py
%load_ext dotenv
# the AIRFLOW_HOME env var must be an absolute file system path 
# if the Notebook is relative to where the `airflow.db` Sqlite DB is.
%dotenv ../path-to-env-file/.env
```

I do see the expected file system path, so `AIRFLOW_HOME` points to the place where the Sqlite database `airflow.db` is - the Jupyter environment `print`s the correct path:

```py
print(os.getenv("AIRFLOW_HOME"))
```

The Sqlite DB was previously created with commands like `airflow db init` (same old `AIRFLOW_HOME`), also I added some connections I use in the DAG with `airflow connections add ...`.

All this stuff works either via the Airflow Webserver + scheduler or via the command:

```sh
airflow tasks test \
    --subdir ../dags \
    'my_dag_id' 'my_task_id' "${TODAY}"
```

- All these configuration details did go from the `airflow` command invocations into the Sqlite DB.
- I do see all the Airflow DB tables in that Sqlite DB.
- I do see the rows in those tables.
- All the commands work as expected.

Now I want to do the same as above, but with a DAG defined in a Jupyter notebook, so going back to that, when I do this in Python:

```py
from airflow.api.client.local_client import Client

c = Client(None, None)
c.trigger_dag(dag_id='my_dag_id', run_id='test_run_id', conf={})
```

Then I see a long stacktrace with at the beginning this message:

```
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
```

and at the bottom this message:

```
OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: dag
[SQL: SELECT dag.dag_id AS dag_dag_id, dag.root_dag_id AS dag_root_dag_id, dag.is_paused AS dag_is_paused, dag.is_subdag AS dag_is_subdag, dag.is_active AS dag_is_active, dag.last_parsed_time AS dag_last_parsed_time, dag.last_pickled AS dag_last_pickled, dag.last_expired AS dag_last_expired, dag.scheduler_lock AS dag_scheduler_lock, dag.pickle_id AS dag_pickle_id, dag.fileloc AS dag_fileloc, dag.owners AS dag_owners, dag.description AS dag_description, dag.default_view AS dag_default_view, dag.schedule_interval AS dag_schedule_interval, dag.max_active_tasks AS dag_max_active_tasks, dag.max_active_runs AS dag_max_active_runs, dag.has_task_concurrency_limits AS dag_has_task_concurrency_limits, dag.has_import_errors AS dag_has_import_errors, dag.next_dagrun AS dag_next_dagrun, dag.next_dagrun_data_interval_start AS dag_next_dagrun_data_interval_start, dag.next_dagrun_data_interval_end AS dag_next_dagrun_data_interval_end, dag.next_dagrun_create_after AS dag_next_dagrun_create_after 
FROM dag 
WHERE dag.dag_id = ?
 LIMIT ? OFFSET ?]
[parameters: ('my_dag_id', 1, 0)]
```

But the `dag` table is there, `AIRFLOW_HOME` is pointing to that Sqlite DB and the table contains the expected row:

```sql
-- this shows the expected row
SELECT * FROM dag WHERE dag_id = 'my_dag_id'
```

How do I run the DAG programmatically from Python or Jupyter?

Answer (score 0):

First off, can you run the DAG yourself through the Airflow UI? It sounds like the Airflow DB may not be initialized correctly. Try a reset, running through the "normal" patterns, then moving forward.

Note: The command to initialize the DB is `airflow initdb`, not `airflow db init`.

Second, I'd recommend using the [Airflow API](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/post_dag_run) to trigger your DAGs through Python rather than using the local client, or by using the [CLI](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#dags).